# Convenience function to get daylight saving time dates for a certain year

Tags: python, dst

I have seen several questions / answers here on stackoverflow regarding the question how to detect whether a certain (timezone aware) `datetime` value is a daylight saving time value.

As this is a little bit inconvenient for my use case:

Is there any functionality in Python where I supply

- the year and
- the timezone

as input and get something back like:

- datetime (tuple) representing the start of the DST period
- datetime (tuple) representing the end of the DST period

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the standard [`tzinfo` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) that will return what you're looking for.  However it's possible to test a particular date with `tzinfo.dst()` to see whether it's part of the daylight saving period, so you can do a binary search to find the transition.